# SqlException: Invalid column name 'EmployeeID1'

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, database-connection, visual-studio-2019

I'm currently trying to make a ASP.NET Core Web Application with Visual Studio 2019. The apps purpose is to display all the data accessed from a localdb database that I imported. The application should output all the information correctly into a table and the user should be able to create a new record, edit, delete and also view the details of the one individual record on a different screen.

The error I keep getting at the moment when I try to boot up the application is the following:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'EmployeeID1'.

The following screenshot is the database structure I'm trying to pull data from:

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp9cb.jpg)

This screenshot is the file structure:

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hROBR.jpg)

This is how I'm trying to display the information in the table:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIi4j.jpg)

The error that is being displayed when I boot the application is the following:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'EmployeeID1'.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+ <>c.b__122_0(Task result)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask.InnerInvoke()
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task currentTaskSlot)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext *, bool buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync(TState state, Func> operation, Func>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIterator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate*(IAsyncEnumerable source, TAccumulate seed, Func accumulator, Func resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       WebApp2.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in Index.cshtml.cs
>       -

```
        //public IList<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
        public IList<Employee> Employees { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Employees = await _context.Employees.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory+NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The main message it was saying to me throughout that is that the error lies within the following code:

```
 Employees = await _context.Employees.ToListAsync();
```

The following code is what I have for my Employee.cs file in the Models folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApp2.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string TitleOfCourtesy { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string HomePhone { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public int ReportsTo { get; set; }
        public string PhotoPath { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This next code is what I currently have for my index.cshtml.cs file. The error is coming from the last line of code this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApp2.Models;

namespace WebApp2
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WebApp2.Models.Northwind _context;

        public IndexModel(WebApp2.Models.Northwind context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        //public IList<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
        public IList<Employee> Employees { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Employees = await _context.Employees.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only new to this and don't have much of an understanding as to why this is happening so any help is appreciated. There is some answers up on stackoverflow regarding this issue but from the answers I wasn't entirely sure how to tailor it to my situation. I hope I have gave enough details as to why this may be happening. If not, please ask for more info and I can let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Would also like to point out that I don't need to display the "photo" field at all and is why I left it out of my employee.cs file.

Comment: Why do you have a collection of Employees inside the class Employee? What is the relationship that you are trying to represent with that property? What happens if you comment out that property?

Comment: It's really confusing but I'm trying to implement this tutorial that I followed here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1 with my other application that properly connects to the imported database. The likes of the Index.cshtml.cs is connecting to that employees class. As well as the Edit.cshtml.cs, Details.cshtml.cs, Delete.cshtml.cs and Create.cshtml.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public ICollection Employees { get; set; }

You need to configure `ReportsTo` as the Foreign Key property a Manager Navigation property. EG

```
 public int ReportsTo { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey(nameof(Employee.ReportsTo))]
 public virtual Employee Manager {get;set;}

 public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is what I currently have in my table definition for the Employees table: CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Employees] FOREIGN KEY ([ReportsTo]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmployeeID]),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Birthdate] CHECK ([BirthDate]<getdate()) What would I need to change this to?

Comment: Right, but you haven't tole EF that ReportsTo is the foreign key property.

Comment: When I insert the code you provided into the employees.cs file, it says the type or namespace name "ForeignKey" could not be found, so what else do I change? Sorry just not very good with this type of work.

Comment: Try adding: `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` or look at the Quick Refactorings in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks man. It got the main error out of the way that I was having but got a different error showing up now that I think I'll potentially know how to fix. Appreciate it.